# Can a Tomcat7/Java/Mysql/Ant application run on Openshift? If so, how to install the jdbc driver?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ant, openshift, opengts

I'm trying to install OpenGTS on Red Hat's Openshift cloud platform.

OpenGTS is a Java/Tomcat7/Mysql/Ant application, so I created a JbossEWS app on Openshift, installed the standard Mysql cartridge, and an Ant cartridge I found online.
Our application does not have to be scalable, so that's what I chose.
I add a call to Ant in Openshift's build hook.

So far it has been impossible to install the jdbc driver however:
As I'm using Ant, I deleted the pom.xml for Openshift's standard Maven.
Neither is there a standalone.xml in JbossEWS. (There is one for JbossEAP).
Java's ext/lib directories are not accessible on Openshift.

So I copied the jdbc driver jar in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR,
but nevertheless, when started, JbossEWS complains it cannot find a suitable jdbc driver for Mysql.

Is it even possible to run OpenGTS on Openshift?

Answer (score 0):

It is comment about above question so we are following this link.
Here is the link https://blog.openshift.com/jndi-tomcat-configuration-howto/
And also catalina.properties file

common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../app-root/data/*.jar